# Can't login to any Google apps, error pops ups each time attempted

Tags: google-play-store, samsung, gmail, samsung-galaxy-s-5, google-play-services

I recently bought a Samsung Galaxy s5 and am unable to login to any google apps. I've tried signing in through all google related apps (play, youtube, gmail) and have tried 3-4 different accounts but each time I try to login an error pops up saying "Unfortunately Google Play Services has stopped working". I've tried logging in on data and different wifi connections, as well as disabling/ force stopping and re-enabling the google play services app, even making a new gmail account but nothing has worked so far. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see how low your Memory is and try Uninstalling some unneeded Apps...then Force Stop All Apps & Unneeded Resources THEN try again..Hopefully this will help...  Not an end all Be All...just a possibility...

Comment: It's a new phone and i haven't downloaded any app and there's about 10gb of free space.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here with a S5 active .I heard that it would help to go I'm app manager and stop all the Google play services updates that are on and it would put back what was needed cieaner. Would it?  I'd I can't figure it out I'm going to go the apk route. It worked for.me when Google play just showed and error for days if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Google Play services Update.Try it.If works great.If not do a factory reset.